# OData v4 Resource not found for the segment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

The following OData configuration is throwing an error with message: "...Resource not found for the segment...".

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder
{
    Namespace = "Company",
    ContainerName = "CompanyContainer"
};

builder.EntitySet<ModelA>("AModels");
builder.EntitySet<ModelB>("BModels");
builder.EntitySet<ModelC>("CModels");

// EDIT register GlobalStats as a ComplexType
builder.ComplexType<GlobalStats>();

builder.Function("Functions.GlobalStats").Returns<GlobalStats>();

var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();

config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "Default", routePrefix: "odata", model: edmModel);
```

And controller:

```
public class GlobalController : CompanyController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("Company.Functions.GlobalStats")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetGlobalStats()
    {
        var stats = await Company.GlobalStats.GetAsync();
        return Ok(stats);
    }
}
```

The idea is to have an endpoint like the following:

http://api.company.com/odata/Company.Functions.GlobalStats

Please help me in figuring out what am I missing with this configuration.

**EDIT #1**

I also tried registering `GlobalStats` as a ComplexType. Still no luck.

**EDIT #2**

The following is the exact error message:

> An exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.OData.dll
>   but was not handled in user code.
>
> Additional information: The path template
>   'Company.Functions.GlobalStats' on the action 'GetGlobalStats' in
>   controller 'Global' is not a valid OData path template. Resource not
>   found for the segment 'Company.Functions.GlobalStats'.

Comment: Do you *want* to be calling it with a namespace?

Comment: @TomDoesCode Yes, it's cleaner I think, although if for some obscure reason I can't make it work with the namespace, well then there is no longer a choice I guess.

Comment: I'm going to try again with getting it to work with the namespace but to get it to work without the namespace, but in the meantime, you should be able to just remove `Company.Functions.` from parameter for the `ODataRoute` attribute and the `Functions.` from the parameter for the `Function` function call to get it to work without the namespace

Answer (score 0):

1. Define an unbound function:

   ```
   modelBuilder.Function("Company.Functions.GlobalStats").Returns<GlobalStats>();
   ```
2. Map your odata route:

   ```
   config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", model);
   ```
3. Define a route attribute for the method in the controller:

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   [ODataRoute("Company.Functions.GlobalStats")]
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetGlobalStats()
   {
       // your code
   }
   ```
4. Call it with http://host/odata/Company.Functions.GlobalStats

Comment: Thanks but this works IF the namespace is not defined "globally", which I'm doing.

Answer (score -1):

Call unbound function should only use the unbound function name after the service root, regardless the namespace.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please explain it with some code? What I understand is to remove the `Function.GlobalStats` and leave it only `GlobalStats`. If that's the case, then I already tried it and it didn't work